# EmguCV cvextern System.DllNotFoundException Android

Tags: android, xamarin, emgucv

When im running my application im getting this error "EmguCV cvextern System.DllNotFoundException". In desktop i must create the folders x86 and x64 and put the dll into then, but when im using Android (with Xamarin) what must i do?

PS: i'm using Demo license.

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: cvextern
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Emgu.CV.CvInvoke:RedirectError (Emgu.CV.CvInvoke/CvErrorCallback,intptr,intptr)
  at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor () [0x0008c] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Emgu.CV.Image`2[TColor,TDepth].AllocateData (Int32 rows, Int32 cols, Int32 numberOfChannels) [0x00013] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Emgu.CV.Image`2[TColor,TDepth].set_Bitmap (Android.Graphics.Bitmap value) [0x0003a] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Emgu.CV.Image`2[TColor,TDepth]..ctor (Android.Graphics.Bitmap bmp) [0x00006] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at EmguCVTeste.ImageProcessing.Process (Android.Graphics.Bitmap imageToProcess) [0x00002] in d:\TCC FUCKING SHIT\App2\App2\ImageProcessing.cs:28
```

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/

Comment: @SushiHangover so... what i have to do? :p